# Prove that the series $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac {x^k} {k}$ does not converge uniformly on the interval $[0, 1)$.

Tags: real-analysis

Prove that the series $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac {x^k} {k}$ does not converge uniformly on the interval $[0, 1)$.

Thoughts:
In order to show this I am not sure where to begin. Do I suppose that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac {x^k} {k}$ does in fact converge and then find some contradiction, or do I show the negation of the definition of uniform convergence is true. Any hints much appreciated.

Comment: if it converged uniformly, the limit would have to be bounded

Comment: @user8268 the limit being the harmonic series?

Comment: sorry for being unclear - I meant that the function $\sum_{k=1}^\infty x^k/k$ on $[0,1)$ would have to be bounded. But you are right that one can see that it's not bounded by comparing with the harmonic series. But perhaps you know what that function is.

Comment: @user8268 i understand what you are saying intuitively but I have no idea how to make this more rigorous using the definition.

Comment: try proving: in $f_n\to f$ uniformly and if each $f_n$ is a bounded function then $f$ is bounded (easy). Then apply in your situation (either knowing that the sum is $-\log(1-x)$ or by noticing that for any $N$ you can find an $x$ s.t. $\sum_{k=1}^\infty x^k/k>\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^N 1/k$, or perhaps you'll find another method)

Comment: [Closely related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/197977/11619). So closely that IMHO this could be closed as a duplicate. Because I answered the target question I will refrain from voting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We know the series converges pointwise, using, for example, the ratio test. Showing that the negation of the definition for uniform convergence is true is facilitated by the following argument.

Let

$$S(x) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k}.$$

Uniform convergence requires for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists an integer $N(\epsilon)$ independent of $x$ such that if $n \geqslant N(\epsilon)$ then for every $x \in [0,1)$ we have

$$\left|\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{x^k}{k}  - S(x)\right| = \sum_{k = n+1}^ \infty \frac{x^k}{k} < \epsilon,$$

which implies, for all $n \geqslant N(\epsilon),$

$$\sup_{x \in [0,1)}\sum_{k = n+1}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k} < \epsilon,$$

or, equivalently,

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\sup_{x \in [0,1)}\sum_{k = n+1}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k}= 0$$

However, for all $n$,

$$\sup_{x \in [0,1)} \sum_{k=n+1}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k} \geqslant \sup_{x \in [0,1)} \sum_{k=n+1}^{2n} \frac{x^k}{k} \geqslant \sup_{x \in [0,1)} n \frac{1}{2n}x^{2n} = \frac{1}{2},$$

and

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\sup_{x \in [0,1)}\sum_{k = n+1}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k} \neq 0.$$

Thus, the series fails to converge uniformly on $[0,1)$.

Comment: Interesting. why are you indexing with $k=n+1$

Comment: Because if $S(x)$ is the sum of the series then $|\sum_{k=1}^n (x^k/k) - S(x)| = \sum_{k=n+1}^\infty (x^k/k)$.  Uniform convergence requires that to be less than $\epsilon$ for sufficiently large $n > N(\epsilon)$ for every $x \in [0,1)$. And the negation of that is my starting point.

Comment: I'm still slightly confused I'm afraid. Are you saying that the sum from $n+1$ to infinity must approach 0 as $n$ goes to infinity?

Comment: I'll add some more detail to the answer which should clear things up.

Comment: I am also not sure how you arrived at the last inequality. Thanks for the help immensely btw.

Comment: The last inequality: the sum from $n+1$ to $2n$ has n terms each greater than $x^{2n}/2n$ when $x <1$.

Comment: Much Appreciated!!

Comment: @IntegrateThis: Glad to help.