# Show that the series $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^k}{k}$ does not converge uniformly on $(-1,1)$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification, uniform-convergence

Show that the series $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{x^k}{k}$ does not converge uniformly on $(-1,1)$. (Hint: Show that the sequence of partial sums is not Cauchy in the sup-norm.)

*Proof:* Let $s_n = \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\dfrac{x^k}{k}$. We need to show that there exists $\epsilon>0$ such that for all $N\in\mathbb{N}$ and for $n \geq N$ implies $\|s_n-s_N\|_{\sup} \geq \epsilon$. As a matter of fact, I claim that this must be true for any $\epsilon >0$ we choose. So let $\epsilon >0$. But, 
\begin{align}
\|s_n-s_N\|_{\sup} &= \|\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}\dfrac{x^k}{k} - \sum\limits_{k=1}^{N}\dfrac{x^k}{k}\|_{\sup}   \\
&= \|\sum\limits_{k=N+1}^{n}\dfrac{x^k}{k}\|_{\sup}   \\
&= \sum\limits_{k=N+1}^{n}\dfrac{1}{k}
\end{align}
which is a harmonic series and will diverge to infinity as $n\to\infty$. $\blacksquare$

Comment: Your proof is fine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A dubious proof using Weierstrass-M test for $\sum^n_{k=1}\frac{x^k}{k}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/197977/a-dubious-proof-using-weierstrass-m-test-for-sumn-k-1-fracxkk)

Comment: you could calculate the value of series explicitly by integrating  the simple geometric series ...  then you will see that it is  unbounded on $(-1,1)$.